# in recursive function case nil is not executed

Tags: scala, recursion

I have function that is recursive, but the case `Nil =>`
does not work and I have `StackOverflowError`. I do not understand why is it not catching the `Nil` after the tail is always passed into the function it should be empty at some point.

```scala
    def parser(lex: List[Any], acc: Int, myTree: ListBuffer[Any]): Any = lex match {
    case Nil => this.tree += myTree // inside class attached created new list.
    case (x: Tokens) :: xs =>
      if (x.getType == "variable") {
        println("count variable type found: " + (acc + 1))
        var nextEle = getElement(acc + 1)
        nextEle.getValue match {
          case "=" => myTree += new Node("assignment", x.getValue, getElement(acc + 2).getValue)
          case "<" => myTree += new Node(nextEle.getValue.toString, x.getValue, getElement(acc + 2).getValue)
          case _ =>
        }
        //myTree += new Node(x.getType, x.getValue, null)
      }
      parser(xs, acc + 1, myTree)
    }
```

Comment: How big is your input? Does it work with smaller input?

Comment: Could you provide StackOverflowError stack trace example, please? Not all, but just an top part. Thanks

Comment: It looks odd that in some cases you are accessing `getElement(acc+2)` but only passing `acc+1` to the recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method cannot be optimised by the compiler to a loop, so it is putting data on the stack for each recursive call. You should always annotate methods that are intended to be optimised in this way to check that it is really happening. 
Annotate with `@annotation.tailrec` to check that the compiler really is not using the stack for recursive calls.

To fix this, make the method either `private` or `final`.

```
@annotation.tailrec
final def parser(lex: List[Any], acc: Int, myTree: ListBuffer[Any]) ...
```

---

The use of `Any` here is also worrying. The code won't work unless `lex` is `List[Tokens]`, so why not put that in the function signature? And `myTree` looks like `ListBuffer[Node]`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise I will try that with private function ... regards to list I'm new to scala but you are right I should have put Tokens there. Thanks

Comment: I suppose this is tail-rec function, because next similar code `@annotation.tailrec def parser(lex: List[String]): Unit = lex match {
    case Nil => println("finish")
    case x :: xs => println(x); parser(xs)
  }``` compiles for me on Scala 2.12

Comment: @IvanKurchenko You are probably defining it in an `object`. Try putting it in a `class`

Comment: yeah it compiles but I have stack Overflow at the end... it does the job but at the end is Stackoverflow even after I have changed to private... 
It is not actually tailrecursive.. only recursive..
tail recursive is method def inside another def method.. This is only one def.

Comment: @Tim Yes, you totally are right, I need to add `final` as well, thanks. But, my point was that this function seems like a tail-rec, and maybe this issue, somewhere inside the match block, not with `lex` matching itself. Thank you for your answer and advice!

Comment: @zetek The `parser` in the question is tail recursive, so perhaps there is some other code that you did not put in the question? I'm not sure what you mean by "method def inside another def method",  but that has nothing to do with tail recursion.

Comment: def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def iter(x: Int, result: Int): Int =
    if (x == 
) result
    else iter(x - 1, result * x)

  iter(n, 
)
}
But you are right it is tail recursive because I did a little bit more research and I found out that it does not have to be inside another method ... So please scrap that.. I'm new to high level programming and learning everyday. This issue I do not understand why is  it going into stackOverFlow.. it should end after the parser receive tail each time is called.

Comment: @zetek If your version of `parser` compiles with `@annotation.tailrec` then the stack overflow is not coming from the recursive call. It must be in one of the methods called inside `parser` such as `getElement` or `getValue`. Comment out code until the stack overflow goes away.

Comment: @Tim no it was my fault.. I did @ annotation.tailrec do you notice is space there after @
I put it now together and using final def and is fine ... Works like baby :)

Thanks guys.. I did not know that was the issue

Comment: @zetek You can accept this answer to show that it fixed your problem.